# Python: finding all words with vowels in place of asterisks

Tags: python

I want to get a list of all possible words with vowels where the asterisks are. For example: for the string '*ppl*', the program should return a list containing 'appla', 'apple', 'appli', 'applo', 'applu', 'eppla', 'epple',..., 'upplu'.

The program below only returns: ['appl*', 'eppl*', 'ippl*', 'oppl*', 'uppl*', 'uppla', 'upple', 'uppli', 'upplo', 'upplu'].

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'


def find_words (word):
    # find the positions of the asterisks and put them into a list
    listFromWord = list(word)
    wilds = []
    for i, x in enumerate(listFromWord):
        if x == '*':
            wilds.append(i)

    # find all words with vowels at the indexes and put them into a list       
    possibleWords = []
    possibleWord = list(word)
    for i in wilds:
        for letter in VOWELS:
            possibleWord[i] = letter          
            possibleWords.append(''.join(possibleWord))

    return(possibleWords)

a = find_words('*ppl*')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'


def find_words (word):
    # find the positions of the asterisks and put them into a list
    listFromWord = list(word)
    wilds = []
    for i, x in enumerate(listFromWord):
        if x == '*':
            wilds.append(i)

    # find all words with vowels at the indexes and put them into a list       
    possibleWords = []
    possibleWord = list(word)
    for i in wilds:
        for letter in VOWELS:
            possibleWord[i] = letter   
            if '*' in possibleWord:
                possibleWords += find_words(''.join(possibleWord))
            else:
                possibleWords.append(''.join(possibleWord))

    return(possibleWords)

a = find_words('*ppl*')
print(a)

# ['appla', 'apple', 'appli', 'applo', 'applu', 'eppla', 'epple', 'eppli', 'epplo', 'epplu', 'ippla', 'ipple', 'ippli', 'ipplo', 'ipplu', 'oppla', 'opple', 'oppli', 'opplo', 'opplu', 'uppla', 'upple', 'uppli', 'upplo', 'upplu', 'uppla', 'upple', 'uppli', 'upplo', 'upplu']
```

Your program only iterates `len(wilds)*len(VOWELS)` times, which is not what you want in output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product` and `repeat` functions from `itertools` to produce vowels combinations. Than just generate word for each combination:

```
from itertools import product, repeat

VOWELS = 'aeiou'


def find_words(word):
    result = [word.replace('*', '{}').format(*x)
              for x in product(*repeat(VOWELS, word.count('*')))]
    return result


print(find_words('*ppl*'))
```

Output:

```
['appla', 'apple', 'appli', 'applo', 'applu', 'eppla', 'epple', 'eppli', 'epplo', 'epplu', 'ippla', 'ipple', 'ippli', 'ipplo', 'ipplu', 'oppla', 'opple', 'oppli', 'opplo', 'opplu', 'uppla', 'upple', 'uppli', 'upplo', 'upplu']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion plus generators:

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"
def words(s):
    if s:
        for w in words(s[1:]):
            if s[0] == '*':
                for v in VOWELS:
                    yield v + w
            else:
                yield s[0] + w
    else:
        yield ''

for a_word in words("*ppl*"):
    print(a_word)
```